# changing a string value throws segmentation fault

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does simple C code receive segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-does-simple-c-code-receive-segmentation-fault)

Hi,

check out the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char* a = "z.x.f.t.e.a";
    char* b = ".";
    updateStr(a,b);
    return 0;
 }
 int updateStr(char str[], const char* delim) {

     int i=0;
     int wordsCounter = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (contains(delim,str[i])) {
            printf("CONTAINED %c\n",str[i]);  //debug
            str[i] = SEPERATOR;
            wordsCounter++;
        }
    i++;
    }
    //REST OF THE CODE....
return wordsCounter;
}
```

updateStr replaces each '.' with ';' (SEPERATOR). However, the line str[i] = SEPERATOR;
throws segmentation fault and i don't have a clue why. what is the reason and how can i fix it?

thanks everyone

Comment: you should declare explicitly `a` to be a char array, not a char pointer

Comment: @Carl Agree, but the title might be different enough so as not to be found in a quick search.

Answer (score 2):

`char *a = "blah";` declares a pointer to a string literal.  These cannot be altered (well, the result is undefined).  You may want to try `char a[] = "blah";` instead, as this gives you a character array.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to modify string constants.  Use an array instead.

```
char[] a = "z.x.f.t.e.a";
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a pointer to a string literal (which you cannot modify).  Change its definition.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char a[] = "z.x.f.t.e.a"; /* will be on the stack */
    char* b = ".";
    updateStr(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```