# SIGSEGV on modifying char * element

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, char-pointer

In the below program,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
  const char *str1 = "abc";
  char *str2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
  str2= "def";
  str2[1]='s';
  printf("str2 is %s", str2);

}
```

---

Debugger :

```
(gdb) ptype str1                                                                                                                         
type = const char *                                                                                                                      
(gdb) ptype str2                                                                                                                         
type = char *                                                                                                                            
(gdb) n                                                                                                                                  
7         str2[1]='s';                                                                                                                   
(gdb) n               

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                                                     
0x00000000004005ab in main () at main.c:7                                                                                                
7         str2[1]='s';                                                                                                                   
(gdb)
```

---

SIGSEGV on `str2[1] = 's';`

As per my understanding, one cannot modify `abc` pointed by `st1`, due to declaration `const char *st1 = "abc"`, where string literal is constant.

Why `char *` type `str2` does not allow modifying the elements? Is stringliteral `def` also a constant string literal.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: [changing a string value throws segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3550171/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what happens:

1. `str2` is allocated with `malloc()` and points to the newly allocated buffer of 4 chars
2. You change the value (address) of `str2` to the address of `"def"`, which is read-only (think of it as a part of your program)
3. You try to change `"def"`
4. You are not able to free the memory because you actually lost the address of it when you assigned `str2` to the address of `"def"`

Answer (score 1):

As per C standars

string literal `("def")` will be stored in the data section, in a read-only page.

So you can not modify its memory.

---

You can modify the content of the `str2` pointer. It means you can point str2 to something else memory. But memory allocared for `string literal "def"` can not be modified.

---

```
  str2= "def";
```

**By doing this you are not copying "def" in your malloced memory.
Instead "def" is getting allocated in read only region and you are assigning its address to str2.**

**If you want to store that "def" in to malloced space then use
strcpy of memcpy.**

Answer (score 0):

The `str2 = "def";` statement changes the value of `str2`. `str2` points to the string literal "def" after the assignment leading to the following crash. At least, it is so on my RHEL 7.1 with gcc 4.8.3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store "abc" in the string buffer you have just allocated, you have to use `strcpy()`, as in `strcpy(str2, "abc")`. As pointed out by other users, using `str2 = "abc"` will change the memory address `str2` is pointing to instead of doing that, and that new address refers to a read-only section that cannot be modified.

Answer (score -1):

Issues:

```
  char *str2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
```

> This means that you have asked for 4 bytes of space in the memory for your personal use and you have been granted with the starting address of the space.

```
  str2= "def";
```

> You got your personal address but now you are changing your address to point to the enchanting "def" which belongs to Read-Only Data section of the memory (String literals). This means that the original address allocated is dangling and cannot be traced back.

Issues:

- Dangling pointer wherein the address would be untraceable.
- you won't be able to free it.

`str2[1]='s';`

> Ohh and now you are trying to be a rebel by trying to change the read only section's content.

Issues:

- Trying to overwrite a read only segment which is not allowed.
- SIGSEGV  is causes i.e an error(signal) caused by an invalid memory reference or a segmentation fault).

What you might be actually be trying:

- Allocating memory for your work (the 4 bytes)
- Overwriting content to that memory `strcpy(str2, "def");`
- `str2[1] = 's'` would also work then.
- Please do free the `str2` variable as you were the one who asked for it. (With great powers come great responsibility) ;)